# Varchar to decimal oracle 11g

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

how to convert varchar to decimal without rounding off.Currently oracle is rounding it off to 5 decimal digits for eg if the varchar data is 1.00037388  then the result data after using the   ----`cast(EN_Cent as decimal(10,9))` cast to decimal function as 1.00037.Need to prevent this from happening

thanks

sri

Comment: It doesn't appear that the `cast` is the problem.  If the data is being rounded, it's being rounded somewhere else.  SQL> select cast( '1.00037388' as decimal(10,9) )
  2    from dual;

CAST('1.00037388'ASDECIMAL(10,9))
---------------------------------
                       1.00037388

Comment: Hi Justin, this is still not working ,When i tried this on the result is below                                                           select cast( '1.00037388' as decimal(10,9) )from dual
1.00037

Comment: What tool are you using?  If you are using SQL*Plus, what is your column formatting set to?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `cast` syntax (see [SQLFiddle exmaple](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31875/0)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with your client.

You need to increase the number of digits you are using after the decimal.

[image: Global Preferences]

Set to 5:
[image]

Set to 10:
[image]